Can't get @ionic/angular to work with Jest
I keep getting errors such as:
Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module '@ionic/angular' from 'src/app/facades/user/user.facade.ts'

    Require stack:
      src/app/facades/user/user.facade.ts
      src/app/facades/user/user.facade.spec.ts

      12 | import { createUser, getUser, patchUser, updateUser } from 'src/app/store/auth/auth.actions';
      13 | import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
    > 14 | import { AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';
     | ^
  15 | import { Device } from '@capacitor/device';
  16 |
  17 | @Injectable({

  at Resolver._throwModNotFoundError (node_modules/.pnpm/jest-resolve@29.7.0/node_modules/jest-resolve/build/resolver.js:427:11)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/app/facades/user/user.facade.ts:14:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/app/facades/user/user.facade.spec.ts:3:1)

I have the following jest configuration:
import { compilerOptions } from './tsconfig.json'
import type { JestConfigWithTsJest } from 'ts-jest'

const jestConfig: JestConfigWithTsJest = {
    globals: {
        'ts-jest': {
            tsconfig: 'tsconfig.spec.json',
            isolatedModules: true,
        },
    },
    roots: ["<rootDir>"],
    preset: 'jest-preset-angular',
    setupFilesAfterEnv: '<rootDir>/src/setup.jest.ts',
    globalSetup: "jest-preset-angular/global-setup",
    modulePaths: [compilerOptions.baseUrl], // <-- This will be set to 'baseUrl' value
    moduleDirectories: ["<rootDir>", "node_modules"],
    moduleNameMapper: {
        '@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc': '<rootDir>/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/ngcc/main-ngcc.js',
    },
    transformIgnorePatterns: [`node_modules/(?!.*\\.mjs$)`],
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.(ts|js|html)$': 'jest-preset-angular',
    },
    resolver: '<rootDir>/jest.resolver.js',
    snapshotSerializers: [
        'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/no-ng-attributes',
        'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/ng-snapshot',
        'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/html-comment',
    ],
};

export default jestConfig

My tsconfig.json
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "downlevelIteration": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "module": "CommonJS",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "importHelpers": true,
        "target": "ES2022",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "preserveSymlinks": true,
        "strictNullChecks": false,
        "strictFunctionTypes": true,
        "strictBindCallApply": false,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "lib": [
            "ES2022",
            "dom"
        ],
        "useDefineForClassFields": false
    },
    "angularCompilerOptions": {
        "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
        "strictInjectionParameters": true,
        "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
        "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
        "strictTemplates": false
    }
}

And my tsconfig.spec.json
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true,
        "outDir": "./out-tsc/spec",
        "module": "CommonJS",
        "types": [
            "jest",
        ]
    },
    "files": [
        "src/polyfills.ts"
    ],
    "include": [
        "src/*.spec.ts",
        "src/*.d.ts"
    ]
}

And this is how I defined it in Angular.json:
    "test": {
      "builder": "@angular-builders/jest:run",
      "options": {
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json"
      }
    },

Is there a way to fix this? I did try the following but then I get @angular/core/testing
const esModules = ['@ionic'].join('|');
transformIgnorePatterns: [`node_modules/(?!${esModules})`],

Versions:
    "@angular-builders/jest": "^17.0.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "17.0.6",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "^17.1.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^17.1.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "^17.1.1",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "^17.1.1",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "^17.1.1",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.24.1",
    "@briebug/jest-schematic": "6.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^9.0.0",
    "@jest/globals": "^29.7.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.11",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.10.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.10.0",
    "eslint": "^8.53.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.29.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "^46.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.7.0",
    "jest-preset-angular": "^14.0.3",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.2",
    "ts-node": "^8.3.0",
    "typescript": "~5.2.2"
    "@ionic/angular": "7.6.0",
    "@ionic/core": "^7.6.0",
    "@angular/core": "17.0.6",

I am using modules
See my user.facade file imports:
import { LoginState } from 'src/app/store/auth/auth.reducer';
import { createUser, getUser, patchUser, updateUser } from 'src/app/store/auth/auth.actions';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Device } from '@capacitor/device';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserFacade implements IUserFacade {

And the following is my spec file:
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { UserFacade } from './user.facade';

describe('UserFacade', () => {
  let service: UserFacade;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({});
    service = TestBed.inject(UserFacade);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
});


The error doesn't point to the test file,  but to a specific file. Error states: Cannot find module '@ionic/angular' from 'src/app/facades/user/user.facade.ts'. So you go to that file and make sure it's imported. Also you forgot to mention several important details. ng version? ionic version? modules or standalone??? Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Ah my apologies. I added the versions and the imports were already visible in the error, as you can see I did import that file. But just for clarity's sake I have added the files as well. Hope that helps.

You are missing to code for: user.facade file, in which the error is pointing to. In VS Code if you have ESLint pluign installed, it will point you directly to the line of code that is giving the error.

ESLint does not show any errors there. Also, I do not have any build problems. The page works fine without any issues. Only when I run Jest it gives the mentioned error. I believe it's a Jest configuration error just not sure what exactly.
